# Need to perform automatic smart contract function execution

Tags: smart-contract, eosjs

Can we have a function in a smart contract to be executed automatically after some time?

for example, transfer some tokens after every 5 seconds.

Comment: Call the action as a deferred transaction recursively.

Comment: explain in detail sir please I don't know anything about the deferred transaction?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to push a transaction initially and you have to write a deferred transaction that call itself recursively after a certain period of time. You should also write some basecase . Basecase condition can be stored inside a table (need to check every time).
Deferred transaction  can be seen as **@John Haager** metion.
You can write a **@abi action** that call this transfer action inside you recursion like  this:

```
// @abi action
void  Democontract::actionDemo(account_name from, string memo, uint64_t duration, uint64_t interval)
{
    uint64_t max_delay = 50;
    string appending_char = "1";

    print(int(duration));
    eosio_assert((((memo.length() == 11) || (memo.length() == 12))), "\n check the length of memo");

    //_ttab ttabs(_self, _self);
    // you use table values here from your table (if you are using table in your code )

    eosio::transaction txn{};

    if (duration < interval)
    {
        print("reached final limit all transaction executed---");
    }
    else if (duration >= interval)
    {

        uint64_t delay = 0;

       //call your transfer action here

        if (duration >= interval)
        {
            //delay interval , duration - interval
            print("duration > interval_________\n");
            txn.actions.emplace_back(
                eosio::permission_level(from, N(active)),
                N(contractname),
                N(actionDemo),
                std::make_tuple(from, memo, duration - interval, interval));
            txn.delay_sec = max_delay;
            txn.send(eosio::string_to_name(memo.c_str()), from);
        }
        else if (duration < interval)
        {
            //delay duration, 0
            print("duration <====== interval_________\n");
            txn.actions.emplace_back(
                eosio::permission_level(from, N(active)),
                N(contractname),
                N(actionDemo),
                std::make_tuple(from, memo, uint64_t(0), interval));
            txn.delay_sec = duration;
            txn.send(eosio::string_to_name(memo.c_str()), from);
        }
    }
```

You can also modify this code to execute transaction more more that 45 days interval time.I also don't write transfer action you can call it inline as i mention in comment.duration(suppose you want this for 2 days) and Max_day is the interval you want to execute your action (after a specific time interval) rest of the things you can understand easily.

Answer (score 1):

The deferred transaction method will work for a while, however Block One have said that there is no guarantee that a deferred transaction will execute at all. It could simply fail and in that case your code will probably end up in a bad state if it relies on this 5 second interval transfer.

An alternative method would be to set up a cron job to call the action from a server, although this has the disadvantage of semi-centralising the system.

You can combine both worlds:

1. Create a table that keeps track of the last time the transfer occured.
2. Have your transfer call itself recursively as a deferred transaction.
3. Also call your cron job to make sure that the transaction succeeds.
4. Make sure to include something in the code that says something like `eosio::assert(now() -last_transfer > 5*ONE_SECOND,"Can't call this now, must wait at least 5 seconds");`

Answer (score 0):

A deferred transaction can be created and submit that will be executed at the specified future time.  If you want the action to execute again, then the action can simply schedule a new deferred transaction to invoke itself.

```
// Create a deferred transaction
transaction out{};
out.actions.emplace_back(
        permission_level{_self, "active"_n},
        _self,
        "myaction"_n,
        std::make_tuple(actionParam)
);
out.delay_sec = refundInterval;
out.send(deferredTxID, _self);
```