# Can I use Timers?

Tags: smart-contract

I know that there's no timer in other smart contracts and even this is not possible in regular blockchains. But, EOS uses C++, and they already did lots stuffs which makes smart contracts more usable.

Is there any possibility to implement timers?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a solution to run a transaction in a later time after pushing the transaction, then [deferred transaction](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cpp/docs/communication-model#section-deferred-communication) is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

I am after knowing this too. Not deferred transactions but a looped timer

Timer(6000ms){
Update tables
}
Without having an external script running
Calltocontract(){
Run update
}
As that could fail and leave hours of no update
I guess only one way to find out though and that’s to try it

[Need to perform automatic smart contract function execution](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/3048/need-to-perform-automatic-smart-contract-function-execution)

This is how others do it