# Can smart contract trigger some action on specified timestamp and change certain account balances?

Tags: smart-contract, permissions

Imagine I have a poll with specified timestamp for the end. At that point in time votes should be tallied and voters token balances should be adjusted in both directions (increase and decrease).

How to implement such smart-contract that will change users' balances without their interaction? Is it normal ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by deferred transaction. It's very normal use case, for example, unstaking EOS from CPU and NET bandwidth triggers `refund` action which is executed in 72 hours. In your case, add the action which handles tallying and adjusting balances and push it with time delay (transaction contains field named by `delay_sec`) so as to execute transaction after vote process is over.

Comment: Keep in mind it is possible deferred transactions will not execute as expected. Block.one has mentioned possibly removing them in the future.

Comment: @netuoso Thanks for your comment. Could you let me know where I can find that deferred transaction will be deprecated in the future?

Comment: Not really clear documentation in writing but it has been discussed in various channels where Block.One has expressed concerns regarding deferred transactions. https://eosio.stackexchange.com/a/3255/3333

Comment: @netuoso I see. A failure on deferred transaction will be noticed by `onerror` action, so contract can mitigate side effect of deferred transaction by its handler.